# Please help interpret setuperr.log from failed Win10 1903 Update

Tags: windows-10, updates, windows-10-v1903

I'm trying to update to Win10 1903 from 1803 but keep getting BSOD with 0xc1900101 code.

I've tried removing attached USB devices and disabling my overclock, without success.

Today I learned that there is a setup error log, which you can see below, but I don't understand what it's telling me.  There is definitely a clue in that my 'Windows' folder is on my C: drive, not my E: drive, not sure why it thinks it would be on E.

```
2019-12-08 09:45:53, Error                 MOUPG  Finalize: Error obtaining Update and Shutdown Key: [0x80070002][gle=0x000000b7]
2019-12-08 09:46:05, Error                 SP     pSPRemoveUpgradeRegTree: failed to delete reg tree HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade[gle=0x00000005]
2019-12-08 09:46:33, Error                 CSI    00000001 (F) 80220008 [Error,Facility=FACILITY_STATE_MANAGEMENT,Code=8] #84859# from CWcmScalarInstanceCore::GetCurrentValue(options = 393216, status = '(null)', value = { type: 40972, bytes ( 12 ): 65006e002d00470042000000 })
[gle=0x80004005]
2019-12-08 09:47:10, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Component with display name: Plugin/{C939EC0F-2F56-4CE8-AF56-2336596A5FA7} already loaded __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::CMXEMigrationXml(class Mig::CPlatform *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::XmlDocument *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *)
2019-12-08 09:54:01, Error                 SP     DRVMIG: Failed to inject driver package in the new OS: E:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\klbackupflt.inf_amd64_b9d1c8fc1791a5cb\klbackupflt.inf. Error: 0x80070057[gle=0x0000007a]
2019-12-08 09:54:05, Error                 SP     DRVMIG: Failed to inject driver package in the new OS: E:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\klhk.inf_amd64_cf3ccc2f94df18cf\klhk.inf. Error: 0x80070057[gle=0x0000007a]
2019-12-08 09:54:05, Error                 SP     DRVMIG: Failed to inject driver package in the new OS: E:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\klpd.inf_amd64_da0ded597745bf66\klpd.inf. Error: 0x80070057[gle=0x0000007a]
2019-12-08 09:54:14, Error                 SP     DRVMIG: Failed to inject driver package in the new OS: E:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\klbackupdisk.inf_amd64_4508e1778b9c5446\klbackupdisk.inf. Error: 0x80070057[gle=0x0000007a]
2019-12-08 09:54:14, Error                 SP     DRVMIG: Failed to inject driver package in the new OS: E:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\klwtp.inf_amd64_21974f4c1c0bcd86\klwtp.inf. Error: 0x80070057[gle=0x0000007a]
2019-12-08 09:54:14, Error                 SP     DRVMIG: Failed to inject driver package in the new OS: E:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\klhk.inf_amd64_317d95882194eb35\klhk.inf. Error: 0x80070057[gle=0x0000007a]
2019-12-08 09:54:16, Error                 SP     DRVMIG: Failed to inject driver package in the new OS: E:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\kldisk.inf_amd64_8f40715b261971dc\kldisk.inf. Error: 0x80070057[gle=0x0000007a]
2019-12-08 09:54:16, Error                 SP     DRVMIG: Failed to inject driver package in the new OS: E:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\kneps.inf_amd64_38b7c16da1534021\kneps.inf. Error: 0x80070057[gle=0x0000007a]
2019-12-08 09:54:16, Error                 SP     DRVMIG: Failed to inject driver package in the new OS: E:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\klmouflt.inf_amd64_16653a13eb343ac8\klmouflt.inf. Error: 0x80070057[gle=0x0000007a]
2019-12-08 09:54:16, Error                 SP     DRVMIG: Failed to inject driver package in the new OS: E:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\klhk.inf_amd64_70253b54f376bdd1\klhk.inf. Error: 0x80070057[gle=0x0000007a]
2019-12-08 09:54:16, Error                 SP     DRVMIG: Failed to inject driver package in the new OS: E:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\klwfp.inf_amd64_342611a61f31d75e\klwfp.inf. Error: 0x80070057[gle=0x0000007a]
2019-12-08 09:54:16, Error                 SP     DRVMIG: Failed to inject driver package in the new OS: E:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\klkbdflt.inf_amd64_18eb6e35ef3a9f33\klkbdflt.inf. Error: 0x80070057[gle=0x0000007a]
2019-12-08 09:54:17, Error                 SP     DRVMIG: Failed to inject driver package in the new OS: E:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\cm_km.inf_amd64_c291cbfd891ebd8f\cm_km.inf. Error: 0x80070057[gle=0x0000007a]
2019-12-08 09:54:18, Error                 SP     DRVMIG: Failed to inject driver package in the new OS: E:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\klhk.inf_amd64_041bd2ab4a51649f\klhk.inf. Error: 0x80070057[gle=0x0000007a]
2019-12-08 09:54:18, Error                 SP     DRVMIG: Failed to inject driver package in the new OS: E:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\klhk.inf_amd64_4d76674cba6d9988\klhk.inf. Error: 0x80070057[gle=0x0000007a]
2019-12-08 09:54:18, Error                 SP     DRVMIG: Failed to inject driver package in the new OS: E:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\sshid.inf_amd64_f7ee2df0b25c9f37\sshid.inf. Error: 0x80070057[gle=0x0000007a]
2019-12-08 10:05:06, Error      [0x080831] MIG    CSIAgent: Invalid xml format: FormatException: Component with display name: Plugin/{C939EC0F-2F56-4CE8-AF56-2336596A5FA7} already loaded __cdecl Mig::CMXEMigrationXml::CMXEMigrationXml(class Mig::CPlatform *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::XmlDocument *,class UnBCL::String *,class UnBCL::String *)
2019-12-08 10:07:18, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {0b23c863-4410-4153-8733-a60c9b1990fb}: TableTextServiceMig!RemoveObsoleteCHSHKLMRegkey - fail to open regkey (software\Microsoft\CTF\TIP\{E429B25A-E5D3-4D1F-9BE3-0C608477E3A1}\LanguageProfile\0x00000804) = 2
2019-12-08 10:07:18, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {0b23c863-4410-4153-8733-a60c9b1990fb}: TableTextServiceMig!ApplySuccess() remove HKLM Registries error
2019-12-08 10:07:18, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {526D451C-721A-4b97-AD34-DCE5D8CD22C5}: [shmig] internal\onecoreuapshell\private\inc\schemacachehelpers.cpp(595)\shmig.dll!00007FFEDFD770A4: (caller: 00007FFEDFD7721E) ReturnHr(1) tid(c4) 8007139F The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.

2019-12-08 10:07:18, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {526D451C-721A-4b97-AD34-DCE5D8CD22C5}: [shmig] internal\onecoreuapshell\private\inc\schemacachehelpers.cpp(618)\shmig.dll!00007FFEDFD7723A: (caller: 00007FFEDFD75148) LogHr(1) tid(c4) 8007139F The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.

2019-12-08 10:07:18, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {526D451C-721A-4b97-AD34-DCE5D8CD22C5}: [shmig] internal\onecoreuapshell\private\inc\schemacachehelpers.cpp(595)\shmig.dll!00007FFEDFD770A4: (caller: 00007FFEDFD7721E) ReturnHr(2) tid(c4) 8007139F The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.

2019-12-08 10:07:18, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {526D451C-721A-4b97-AD34-DCE5D8CD22C5}: [shmig] internal\onecoreuapshell\private\inc\schemacachehelpers.cpp(618)\shmig.dll!00007FFEDFD7723A: (caller: 00007FFEDFD75148) LogHr(2) tid(c4) 8007139F The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.

2019-12-08 10:07:18, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {526D451C-721A-4b97-AD34-DCE5D8CD22C5}: [shmig] internal\onecoreuapshell\private\inc\schemacachehelpers.cpp(595)\shmig.dll!00007FFEDFD770A4: (caller: 00007FFEDFD7721E) ReturnHr(3) tid(c4) 8007139F The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.

2019-12-08 10:07:18, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {526D451C-721A-4b97-AD34-DCE5D8CD22C5}: [shmig] internal\onecoreuapshell\private\inc\schemacachehelpers.cpp(618)\shmig.dll!00007FFEDFD7723A: (caller: 00007FFEDFD75148) LogHr(3) tid(c4) 8007139F The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.

2019-12-08 10:07:18, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {526D451C-721A-4b97-AD34-DCE5D8CD22C5}: [shmig] internal\onecoreuapshell\private\inc\schemacachehelpers.cpp(595)\shmig.dll!00007FFEDFD770A4: (caller: 00007FFEDFD7721E) ReturnHr(4) tid(c4) 8007139F The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.

2019-12-08 10:07:18, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {526D451C-721A-4b97-AD34-DCE5D8CD22C5}: [shmig] internal\onecoreuapshell\private\inc\schemacachehelpers.cpp(618)\shmig.dll!00007FFEDFD7723A: (caller: 00007FFEDFD75148) LogHr(4) tid(c4) 8007139F The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.

2019-12-08 10:07:18, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ee036dc0-f9b7-4d2d-bb94-3dd3102c5804}: BRIDGEMIG: ParseRegistryIfBridgeExists: offline key (new) = '$OFFLINE_RW_2D8F1358$SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\Bridge'
2019-12-08 10:07:18, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {ee036dc0-f9b7-4d2d-bb94-3dd3102c5804}: BRIDGEMIG: ParseRegistryIfBridgeExists: query bridge presence key failed 0x139f, bridge present = 0
2019-12-08 10:07:18, Error      [0x08038d] MIG    Failure while calling IPostApply->ApplySuccess for Plugin={ServerPath="Microsoft-Windows-DirectoryServices-ADAM-Client\adammigrate.dll", CLSID={43CCF250-2A74-48c6-9620-FC312EC475D6}, ThreadingModel=Apartment}. Error: 0x80070002
2019-12-08 10:07:18, Error                 SP     Error READ, 0x00000002 while gathering/applying object: apply-success, Action,CMXEPlugin,E:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\ReplacementManifests,Microsoft-Windows-DirectoryServices-ADAM-Client\adammigrate.dll,{43CCF250-2A74-48c6-9620-FC312EC475D6},Apartment. Will return 2[gle=0x000000cb]
2019-12-08 10:23:55, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-Dot3svc[@version="10.0.17134.1" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings. Will return 2
2019-12-08 10:23:56, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-feclient[@version="10.0.17134.1" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings. Will return 2
2019-12-08 10:23:56, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-feclient[@version="10.0.17134.1" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [EfsLocalConfig]. Will return 2
2019-12-08 10:23:56, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft-Windows-WwanSvc-ServerCfg[@version="10.0.17134.1" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings. Will return 2
2019-12-08 10:23:56, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft.Windows.WinHTTP[@version="5.1.17134.590" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings. Will return 2
2019-12-08 10:23:56, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft.Windows.WinHTTP[@version="5.1.17134.590" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [ConfigVersion]. Will return 2
2019-12-08 10:23:56, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft.Windows.WinHTTP[@version="5.1.17134.590" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [EventMessageFile]. Will return 2
2019-12-08 10:23:56, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft.Windows.WinHTTP[@version="5.1.17134.590" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [ProviderGuid]. Will return 2
2019-12-08 10:23:56, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft.Windows.WinHTTP[@version="5.1.17134.590" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [TypesSupported]. Will return 2
2019-12-08 10:23:56, Error                 SP     Error WRITE, 0x0000065E while gathering/applying object: State, Microsoft.Windows.WinHTTP[@version="5.1.17134.590" and @arch="amd64" and @culture="neutral" and @context="allUsers"]/settings [WinHttpSettings]. Will return 2
2019-12-08 10:24:04, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {0b23c863-4410-4153-8733-a60c9b1990fb}: TableTextServiceMig!RemoveObsoleteCHSHKLMRegkey - fail to open regkey (software\Microsoft\CTF\TIP\{E429B25A-E5D3-4D1F-9BE3-0C608477E3A1}\LanguageProfile\0x00000804) = 2
2019-12-08 10:24:04, Error      [0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {0b23c863-4410-4153-8733-a60c9b1990fb}: TableTextServiceMig!ApplySuccess() remove HKLM Registries error
```

Is there anything in here that could help fix the BSOD issue?

*Edit: just remembered I have junction points set up for the Documents folder, and a couple others, maybe the entire Users folder, to keep them off my C: drive which is a smallish SSD.  Could the E: references be related to that?

Comment: One cause of this a corrupted file system or insufficient disk space and then failed update.  Do you have at least 30 GB of free space available to do the update?

Comment: @John I’ll check this arvo.  Also see my edit on the OP in case that helps.

Comment: "Could the E: references be related to that?" - Yes;  You have basically moved your profile to another partition by doing that.

Comment: Correct, but the updates can’t deal with the junction points? @Ramhound

Comment: Exactly, moving your profile to another partition, the way you did it has never been supported.  [This](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/resolve-windows-10-upgrade-errors) tool might work for 1803, but 1803 has not been supported for 8 months, so the results might be relevant..

Comment: Ahhh that’s a huge pain!  Thanks for the advice though! @Ramhound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I tried all the things suggested by @JW0914 to no avail.  The next time I tried to update it got stuck in an infinite restart loop that was unfixable.  I had to reinstall from scratch.  My presumption is that my junction points were the cause, so I’ve not done that on this installation.

Answer (score 1):

The following should resolve the issue and *must be completed in the order listed*.

Issue the following in an admin terminal:

1. Cleanup the Component Store (`%WinDir%\WinSxS`):

   ```powershell
   DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
   ```
2. Check for and fix corruption within the Component Store, then *Reboot once completed*:

   ```powershell
   DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
   ```

   - This verifies the backups of all system files against known good copies from the Windows Update servers, so an internet connection is required.
   - If an internet connection cannot be obtained, you will need to use the Windows install ISO's `install.wim` or `install.esd`:

     1. Get the Image Index for the Windows install from the `install.wim`/`install.esd`

        ```powershell
        DISM /Get-Wiminfo /WimFile:"Z:\sources\install.wim"
        ```
     2. Use this in place of #2's command, then *Reboot once completed*:

        ```powershell
        DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:"z:\sources\install.esd":<index#>
        ```
3. Check for and fix system file corruption, then *Reboot once completed*:

   ```powershell
   SFC /ScanNow
   ```

The update should now complete successfully.

Comment: @Nexmo16 No, the user data junction points have no bearing on this.  What's occurring is the update is trying to inject drivers into the driverstore in order to save them into the new `%WinDir%`, but it's having an issue doing so since there's a configuration state error or mismatch within the Component Store (`%WinDir%\WinSxS`).  #1 will correct this, #2 will ensure there are no additional issues with the Component Store, and #3 will ensure there are no issues with any of the system files in `%WinDir%` _(excl. WinSxS, as WinSxS is what SFC relies upon to verify system file hashes against)_.

Comment: @Nexmo16 After re-reading your edit and the log, it could be possible your junction points may be interfering, but try the steps in the answer first before modifying your junction points.  Just an FYI, there shouldn't be any reason to manually create junction points, as all user data directories can be moved via the _Location_ tab under the directory's properties (`%UserProfile%\Documents`, `%UserProfile%\Downloads`, etc.).  `UserProfile%` and `C:\Users` should never be moved, junction points or otherwise, due to the amount of hardlinks contained in `%UserProfile%`.